# Contiki 3.0 - Sky mote not connecting properly

Tags: 16.04

Running ubuntu 16.04, x64. I installed contiki 3.0 without VMware (I'm under the impression I don't need it since I am running ubuntu).

I'm trying to perform the command `sudo make hello-world.upload` using saved target sky. I've scoured the internet and not found a fix that has work for me yet. However, I keep getting the code below:

```
using saved target 'sky'
msp430-objcopy hello-world.sky -O ihex hello-world.ihex
make IHEXFILE=hello-world.ihex sky-reset sky-upload
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
using saved target 'sky'
make -k -j 20 sky-reset-sequence
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
using saved target 'sky'
../../tools/sky/msp430-bsl-linux --telosb -c /dev/ttyUSB1 -r
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-telos-7
Use -h for help
Reset device ...
Done
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
make -j 20 sky-upload-sequence
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
using saved target 'sky'
+++++ Erasing /dev/ttyUSB1
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-telos-7
Use -h for help
Mass Erase...
Transmit default password ...
+++++ Programming /dev/ttyUSB1
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-telos-7
Invoking BSL...
Transmit default password ...
Current bootstrap loader version: 1.61 (Device ID: f16c)
Changing baudrate to 38400 ...
Program ...
42978 bytes programmed.
+++++ Resetting /dev/ttyUSB1
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-telos-7
Use -h for help
Reset device ...
Done
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/liam/contiki/examples/hello-world'
rm hello-world.ihex
```

To my understanding, this did not run correctly and breaks the subsequent command, `make login` which gives me:

```
using saved target 'sky'
../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux -b115200 /dev/ttyUSB1
connecting to /dev/ttyUSB1 (115200)
open: Invalid argument
../../platform/sky/Makefile.common:193: recipe for target 'login' failed
make: *** [login] Error 255
```

I think this means that the mote is not properly connected somehow??

With `make motelist` I receive back that my device is in `/dev/ttyUSB1`, which makes me think that it is properly connected. I've also check`makefile` against [this](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/platform/sky/Makefile.sky) and it seems to be fine.

Could someone advise me how to fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your serialdump-linux execution file in the contiki/tools/sky folder and follow the steps given in the link..

1) http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Hello_World
Everey thing is given clearly in the above link

The above documentation is really good as of now I am also a newbie in this area.

http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/

Comment: could you enumerate the steps that you linked since others may see this later and links can go bad.

Comment: Changed little bit that would be fine every thing is explained clearly in the link step wise